# datetime ISO week says first and last day of year are both in same week

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime-format, python-datetime

I'm running Python 3.8.3 and I found something weird about the ISO Week format (%V) :

**The first day and the last day of 2019 are both in week 1.**

```
from datetime import date
print(date(2019, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-W%V'))
print(date(2019, 12, 29).strftime('%Y-W%V'))
print(date(2019, 12, 31).strftime('%Y-W%V'))
```

Output:

```
2019-W01  
2019-W52  
2019-W01
```

Why does it behave like that?

Comment: Because it is the correct way?

Comment: "The ISO year is slightly offset to the Gregorian year; for example, Monday 30 December 2019 in the Gregorian calendar is the first day of week 1 of 2020 in the ISO calendar, and is written as 2020-W01-1 or 2020W011" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: @Boris so the expected output should be 2020-W01 and not 2019-W01 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fully correct.

As you see in your dates, all of them are in `2019`, so it is correct to get 2019 with `%Y`.

Week number is defined by ISO, and so one week could be considered in previous or in next year.

You need to use `%G` to get year of the week number (`%V`).

Comment: Link to docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes (scroll down to the second table)

Comment: The relevant information from @Boris link above: `ISO 8601 week as a decimal number with Monday as the first day of the week. Week 01 is the week containing Jan 4.`